# custom Allocator compilation difficulties 3

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

Having managed to define a custom allocator, it compiles when Char=char while it doesn΄t when Char=char16_t or char32_t . The allocator allocates all Strings sequentially inside the array m ( may be seen debugging and looking at memory ).

```
#include <string>
#include <limits>

typedef char char8_t; // just for symmetry.

#define charSz 8 // may by 16 or 32. change by hand !

//#define CONCAT_(a,b,c) a ## b ## c
//#define CONCAT(a,b,c) CONCAT_(a,b,c)
//typedef CONCAT(char,charSz,_t) Char; // may be char8_t or char16_t or char32_t 

#if charSz == 8
    #define STR(s) #s
    typedef char8_t Char;
#elif charSz == 16
    #define STR(s) u ## #s
    typedef char16_t Char;
#elif charSz == 32
    #define STR(s) U ## #s
    typedef char32_t Char;
#endif 

typedef int32_t Token;
typedef unsigned char byte;

typedef size_t addr;addr freePos=0;Token freeT=0;
const size_t heapSize=0x400;byte m[heapSize];

addr Allocate(size_t sz){addr t=freePos;freePos+=sz;return t;}
void Deallocate(addr p,size_t sz){/**((size_t*)(m+p))=sz;*/}

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
struct Allocator {
        // http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement

        typedef T value_type;
        typedef T* pointer;
        typedef const T* const_pointer;

    typedef value_type& reference;typedef const value_type& const_reference;

    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

    template<typename U> struct rebind {typedef Allocator<U> other;};

    inline Allocator() {}
        // The initialization of freePos and freeT is done after the class definition.
        //  Doing it in the class creator ins't correct because another intializer of another Allocator
        // class would reinitialize that. 

    inline ~Allocator() {}
    inline Allocator(Allocator const&) {}
    inline addr address(reference r) {return (byte*)(&r)-m;}
    inline addr address(const_reference r) {return (byte*)(&r)-m;}

    //static inline offset_type allocate(size_type n, typename std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0)
    //  offset_type t=freePos;freePos+=n*sizeof(T);return t;
    static inline pointer allocate(size_type n){return (pointer)(m+Allocate(n*sizeof(T)));}

    static void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n){Deallocate((byte*)p-m,sizeof(T)*n);}

    inline size_type max_size() const{ 
       return std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(T);
    }
    inline void construct(pointer p, const T& t) {}
    inline void destroy(pointer p) {}

};

template <typename T>
    bool operator==(Allocator<T> const &, Allocator<T> const &) { return true; }
template <typename T>
    bool operator!=(Allocator<T> const &, Allocator<T> const &) { return false; }

typedef std::basic_string< Char,std::char_traits<Char>,Allocator<Char> > String;

int main(){
  for (size_t i=0;i<sizeof(m);i++) m[i]=0xDD; // fill memory to be able to see changes - especially 0s 

  String s=STR(nice) ;
  String t=STR(very nice) ;
  String u=STR(good) ;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: So what error do you get?

Comment: C11 is a name for the current Standard of the **C** programming language.

Comment: Allocators have to be constructible from rebound allocator types. Take a look at the `X a(b);` requirement.

Comment: @dyp I read the section but I didn't understood what you try to convey.

Comment: If you read the [error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a29916e92ada32e9) for `char16_t` carefully, you'll find "no known conversion for argument 1 from `const Allocator<char16_t>` to `const Allocator<char>&`" In the allocator requirements, let `X == Allocator<char>`, `Y == Allocator<char16_t>`, `Y b;`, then `X a(b);` must be well-formed, that is, there must be a conversion from rebound allocator types.

Comment: @dyp You mean I should add template<typename U> Allocator(U){}

Comment: Well, sort of. Any way to convert from the original to the rebound allocator would have been fine. That conversion should work like the copy constructor, that is, memory allocated via one allocator must be deallocatable through the converted/rebound allocator after converting back: `X x_orig; X x_copy( Y(x_orig) ); assert(x_orig == x_copy);`

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
template<typename U> Allocator(U){}
```

works !